# Does pyc file get created when python project is shipped and executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In pycharm, when I run a project, I notice that a folder **pycache** gets created containing .pyc files. Is that the byte code which is then interpreted by the cpython interpretor?

I know that these pyc files can be deleted without causing harm to the project. However, when python project without pyc files is shipped as an exe or via a framework like flask, then does the interpreter auto generate the pyc files and then convert the byte code into machine code?